# Laravel - Blade Template define sections/include

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-3

Is there a way I don't have to use multiple `@include` for the tabs for some pages.

For example I do something like this

In the section/product-tab1.blade.php

```
<ul class="nav-tabs hidden-xs" role="tablist">
   <li><a href="/something1" role="tab">Category Name 1</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="/something2">Category Name 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the section/product-tab2.blade.php

```
<ul class="nav-tabs hidden-xs" role="tablist">
   <li><a href="/something4" role="tab">Something Name 4</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="/something5">Something  Name 5</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="/something6">Something Name 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the something1.blade.php I would define like this to show tabs:

```
 @include('product-tab1')
```

In the something4.blade.php show tabs:

```
 @include('product-tab2')
```

Also would you use if statement in the view file to define `class="active"` or not? It will get  defined variable from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use an if conditional, a short-if is in fact ver short in this case. An if for a navigation could look something like this (notice this if with Bootstrap classes, you probably want to use different classes).

Ideally you should write a helper for this, but we will just do it with a bit of logic in your view for now. Simply go to the tag you want to set the active class on and put the following in.

```
class="{{ Request::is('your/path') ? 'active' : '' }}"
```

Now that is kind of dirty, but it most certainly works. You should create a helper for it eventually, but you really don't need one for testing or small projects.

A great resource for stuff like this is Laracasts, here is the corresponding video:

https://laracasts.com/lessons/active-states

---

Now for your other issue, I don't know exactly what you are doing or why you referencing those tabs. It's really hard to come up with a good solution this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will watch that video. In regarding to tabs, A few pages will have same tab sections.. A few other pages will have different tabs sections. That is why I want to Referencing those tabs. Understand?

Comment: Ah, well in that case you could create different templates for the different pages if it's only going to be two sets of tabs. Just create a template with one set and one with another and use those. If it's more the way you're doing it is fine.